# How to merge two arrays in one arguments with WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have two arrays for one argument in WordPress custom search functionalities like below

```
// If get community then
if(isset($_GET['community'])){
    $community = $_GET['community'];
    $community_count = count($community);
    for ($i=0; $i < $community_count ; $i++) { 
        $community_array = array(
            'key'       => 'community',
            'value'     => $_GET['community'][$i],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        );
    }
}

// If get features then
if(isset($_GET['ap_features'])){
    $features = $_GET['ap_features'];
    $features_count = count($features);
    for ($i=0; $i < $features_count ; $i++) { 
        $features_array = array(
            'key'       => 'apartment_features',
            'value'     => $_GET['ap_features'][$i],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        );
    }
}
```

I want to merge this two arrays for one search arguments like below

```
// Search ARGS
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'apartment',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array (
            'relation' =>  'AND',
            $community_array
        ),
        array (
            'relation' =>  'AND',
            $features_array
        ),
    )
);
```

here is `$community_array` and `$features_array` when I select only from then like `$community_array` then it's search fine for only `$community_array` but when clicking `$features_array` with `$community_array` then he didn't search anything, I mean now only search single, not mixture. My question is how to search with merge this two arrays.

**Edit after first answer comment**

`var_dump` result

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["key"]=> string(9) "community" 
        ["value"]=> string(12) "eleven_polls" 
        ["compare"]=> string(4) "LIKE" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["key"]=> string(9) "community" 
        ["value"]=> string(22) "activities_coordinator" 
        ["compare"]=> string(4) "LIKE" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(3) { 
        ["key"]=> string(18) "apartment_features" 
        ["value"]=> string(20) "built_in_bookshelves" 
        ["compare"]=> string(4) "LIKE" 
    } 
    [3]=> array(3) { 
        ["key"]=> string(18) "apartment_features" 
        ["value"]=> string(11) "cable_ready" 
        ["compare"]=> string(4) "LIKE" } 
    }
```

Comment: Please check bellow code we have managed.

Comment: Try to use OR after meta_query

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i < $features_count ; $i++) { 
    $features_array[] = array(
        'key'       => 'apartment_features',
        'value'     => $_GET['ap_features'][$i],
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    );
}
```

change the loop code as above so that every apartment features will be pushed to the array otherwise it will fill with only last value from the array as your not pushing but assigning directly. and try the code below

```
    $args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'apartment',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array_merge($community_array, $features_array),
    )
);
```

Comment: can you dump the result of `array_merge($community_array, $features_array)`

Comment: its to be noted that we are using the relation operator 'AND' here and you need to verify its 'OR' or 'AND' to get the right result and I recommend to check the raw query generated like `echo $results->request` and check the query as per above query we are forcing the results to be like all the supplied meta queries and you might need to check the DB for such a result exists or not after applying the above constrains.

Answer (score 0):

```
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');    

if(isset($_GET['community'])){
    $community = $_GET['community'];
    $community_count = count($community);
    for ($i=0; $i < $community_count ; $i++) { 
        $community_array = array(
            'key'       => 'community',
            'value'     => $_GET['community'][$i],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        );
    }

    if(count($community_array) > 1):
        $community_array['relation'] = 'AND';
    endif;

    $meta_query[] = $community_array;
}

// If get features then
if(isset($_GET['ap_features'])){
    $features = $_GET['ap_features'];
    $features_count = count($features);
    for ($i=0; $i < $features_count ; $i++) { 
        $features_array = array(
            'key'       => 'apartment_features',
            'value'     => $_GET['ap_features'][$i],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        );
    }

    if(count($features_array) > 1):
        $features_array['relation'] = 'AND';
    endif;

    $meta_query[] = $features_array;
}

// Search ARGS
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'apartment',
    'meta_query'    => $meta_query
);
```

Comment: Same brother, searching only single, not merging

Comment: You have not need to merge array value just print argument array so you can easy to understand... All ready i have faced this issue before some days.

Comment: relation value based on your requirement change "AND" OR "OR"